# Do gitlab.yml script installs to local machine?

Tags: gitlab-ci, installation-package, gitlab-ci.yml

I thought when you command install something on gitlab yml it install virtually somewhere. But right now I am confused I installed a bunch of stuff and it seems to be installing into my machine.

Comment: Jobs in GitLab pipelines _typically_ run in a temporary Docker container. _When_ do you think things were being installed and on _which_ machine?

Comment: I am on mac. I used gitlab yml to install awscli somehow later when I checked on mac terminal I have aws installed in my machine. That's why I asked.

Comment: Are you hosting GitLab or a runner on your own machine? Or how are you ‘running’ `gitlab.yml` (which should probably be called `.gitlab-ci.yml`, btw) locally?!

Comment: I created runners.